# RangeSlider component does not work inside Filter's shortcut in Polaris Library

Tags: reactjs, shopify, shopify-app, polaris

I am using the [Polaris library by Shopify](https://polaris.shopify.com/components) to build an app. I am using [RangeSlider with dual thumb](https://polaris.shopify.com/components/range-slider) for the filter.

However, when I add it as a **shortcut** inside my [Filters](https://polaris.shopify.com/components/filters), the **slider does not work, i.e., I am not able to drag the ends of the slider**

***Note -** If you go to More Filters -> Money Spent, the slider works fine without any issues, and I am able to drag both ends.*

I tried manipulating the callback, but it didn't help and also does not throw any errors while debugging.

[Reproducible Code Link to CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-darwin-t81u4v?file=/App.js)  => check Money spend filter

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you are saving the data the user enters into `rangeValue`, but the code you have to add the filters (Line 198) is looking at `moneySpent` instead. Since moneySpent is never set, the filter is never added.

Comment: I guess `moneySpent` is used to display the `appliedfilters` tags in the front end. The issue is with the slider itself, if you try to drag the slider -- it does not work on the outside. However, if you go to More Filters -> Money spent -> the slider works completely fine.

Still, I have updated the code where I now set `moneySpent` on `handleRangeSliderChange` .